# How to run hierarchical clustering hclust on large data?

Tags: r, bigdata, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I'd like to run hierarchical clustering on a "large" matrix of dimensions `69878 x 10` but can't manage to because running `hclust` in R requires first computing the pairwise distances and doing so crashes on these dimensions:

```
> str(x)
 num [1:69878, 1:10] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 1 0 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:10] "0.5" "1" "1.5" "2" ...
> d <- dist(x)  
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 18.2 Gb
```

Is there a way to circumvent this limitation?

Comment: Get more memory for your computer? Alternatively you can draw a sample from your data that will fit in your computer memory and cluster that. Decide how many clusters you want and compute the centroids for those clusters. Use the centroids with `kmeans()` on the full data set. Whether this makes sense depends on what you want to do with the results.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53032431/is-it-possible-to-run-a-clustering-algorithm-with-chunked-distance-matrices and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40989003/hclust-in-r-on-large-datasets