# Cannot find the Distance Matrix in Hierarchical Clustering

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, euclidean-distance

I want to perform Hierarchical Clustering in [this](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/wb4jeemgu1e86adawkvma/scaled.dataset.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=elq1ig27z1i6yiml749rlbq7o) dataset (107721 rows and 16 columns). In order to do this I have to calculate the distance matrix. When I use the dist function I get the error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 43.2 Gb

I have searched a lot and I haven't found a solution yet. Also, I saw that errors like this can be handled with bigmemory package. I read the documentation but I didn't understand how to use the functions of the package in order to solve this problem.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your data is too big to compute the distance metric, either use some approximations, if they exist, or reduce your data size.

Comment: you can try to use the [disk frame package](https://diskframe.com/). It is much slower than doing your computations in RAM. It also may be hard on your SSD but if those limitations are not an issue it does provide a lot of utility.

Comment: @user2974951 I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40989003/hclust-in-r-on-large-datasets) and I installed the Rclusterpp package and I used Rclusterpp.hclust in order to do the Hierarchical Clustering